# Searching between two dates in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables and this table name is "rooms" [image: Table Rooms] and other one is "bookings" [image: Table Bookings]

I joined two tables now, I want values when i will search between `book_form = "2016-12-30"` and `book_to = "2016-12-31"` it will be return `true` because this two dates does not exists in the "bookings" table, and when search between `book_form = "2016-12-30"` and `book_to = "2017-01-05"` or `book_form = "2017-01-03"` and `book_to = "2017-01-15"` it will be return false because this date exists in bookings table.

This is my query.

```
select * from rooms join room_book on rooms.room_id = room_book.room_id where status = 'available' and room_book.book_from NOT BETWEEN '2016-12-30' AND room_book.book_to NOT BETWEEN '2016-12-31'
```

---

> **NOTE:** *Sorry actually the column `book_from` date is `2017-01-01` in the bookings table.*

Comment: What does the `NULL` in `book_from`/`book_to` mean? Is it that room 1/A2 is booked from the beginning of time till the end of time or the other way round?

Comment: forget about second row.

Comment: yes it is booked.

Comment: You miss the most important part, what are you trying to do?

Comment: @Troyer I think that part is clear; it's a room booking system. I want a room for dates x to y; it needs to find one that isn't taken throughout that range. The actual problem here is that the field datatypes are unsuitable for it. I.e. dates are text. Store the dates as timestamps and doing greater than/less than becomes trivial

Comment: @LukeBriggs if the date is text you can play with CONVERT() to compare them :)http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10825/compare-a-date-string-to-datetime-in-sql-server

Comment: @Troyer Sure, but that's asking for a whole load of locality problems (and it'll be a lot slower than comparing numbers). The better approach being use a date/timestamp/datetime field to store a date :)

Comment: @LukeBriggs I'm 100% with you, when you need to store a date, use the correct field type, but sometimes we need to do silly things... On this case CONVERT() must solve the problem.

Comment: @Troyer This one's all new - i.e. the screenshots show almost empty tables; better off designing a new database correctly than trying to hack a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple SQL query should return only those rooms without a booking that includes the supplied date:

```
SELECT *
FROM rooms
LEFT JOIN room_book
    ON room_book.room_id = rooms.room_id
    AND 'search_date' BETWEEN room_book.book_from AND room_book.book_to
WHERE rooms.room_id IS NULL
AND rooms.status = 'available'
```

Substitute the date you are searching for *search_date* above.

By using a LEFT JOIN, you will get all of the records in rooms. The IS NULL test in the where clause eliminates those rows that don't have a matching row in room_book.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
from rooms 
join room_book on rooms.room_id = room_book.room_id 
where status = 'available' 
and room_book.book_from >= '2016-12-30' 
AND room_book.book_to <= '2016-12-31'
```

Try like this.

Comment: This will incorrectly perform alphabetical string comparisons, rather than date ones.

Comment: @LukeBriggs Is there a way to force MySQL to perform another form of comparison on DATE or DATETIME fields?

Comment: @parrker9 Yep, see Troyer's comments above about the CONVERT() function :)